# Services calling services

Tags: java, services

The application I'm developing has:

- controllers (they are responsible for processing RESTful API calls),
- services (their methods are being called by controllers, they are responsible for operations with various objects),
- repositories (their method are being by controllers when they are manipulating various objects)
- and so on.

Some operations are asynchronous, so a controller runs this operation *by calling a separate service* and this separate service starts a background job and returns the job ID to the caller. It looks like that:

```
    @DeleteMapping("/hahaha/{id}")
    public Job deleteHahaha(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return jobService.runJob(
                () -> {
                    hahahaService.delete(id);
                }
        );
    }
```

Everything's working fine, but I'm not sure that everything's optimal.

Shouldn't I make `HahahaService.delete()` call `JobService.runjob()` by itself and return a `Job`? Won't it be a bad practice when services are coupled and interdependent? At the same time, `JobService` is a service of another kind than `HahahaService`, `HohohoService` and `KekekeService`, because it's an auxiliary service, so maybe it's OK to use it from another service.

What do you think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't I make `HahahaService.delete()` call `JobService.runjob()` by itself and return a `Job`?

It's important to distinguish between **domain services** (such as `HahahaService`, which houses actual business logic) and **infrastructure services** (such as `JobService`, which handles scheduling, thread pools etc.). You don't want the domain layer to know about infrastructure because domain logic could be reused across different applications which may require different kinds of infrastructure.

Your example with the controller calling `JobService` is the right way to do it, because it's the controller's responsibility to know that it is servicing an asynchronous REST endpoint and to schedule a background job.

If you wanted to build a command-line interface in the future, you can reuse `HahahaService` but the delete operation would likely be synchronous and there would be no need for `JobService` at all.